# Order of nextTicks and microtasks

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I was writting some code I bump into incorrect as I think behaviour of nextTick queue and microtask queue.

Ok, example of the code will be the following:

```
process.nextTick(() => console.log(1));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(3));
setImmediate(() => {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(4));
  process.nextTick(() => console.log(5));
});
```

it will output:

```
2
3
1
5
4
```

However, If I'll wrap that code into `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(() => {
  process.nextTick(() => console.log(1));
  Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2));
  Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(3));
  setImmediate(() => {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(4));
    process.nextTick(() => console.log(5));
  });
})
```

you will see another order of outputs:

```
1
2
3
5
4
```

So why do I see that microtask will be first rather than nextTick without wrapping by `setTimeout`?

###### Node.js version

v18.9.0

Comment: *"it will output:"* That's not what I get on v18.9.0 (or previously on v16.13.2), I get `1 2 3 5 4` regardless, consistently. In any case, it's a **very** bad idea to rely on the order of interaction between `nextTick` and microtasks and such.

Comment: Have you studied [Node's documentation of its event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sure, I've learned node's documentation. Anyway node's devs should remark this implicit behaviour. Also I was getting this strange behaviour on node v12.0. So I don't know how to be with this...

Comment: I've tried with v12.18.3, v13.12.0, v14.9.0, v15.14.0, v16.13.2, v17.1.0, and v18.9.0. I never see the first result you describe. I always consistently get `1 2 3 5 4`, regardless of version, regardless of whether the code is wrapped in a `setTimeout`. Also true for v12.22.10 in replit.com, and [v16.14.2 on onecompiler](https://onecompiler.com/nodejs/3ygrzzedp).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what is wrong with my node in that case?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder finally I've guessed why I got another way of logs. The problem was in `.mjs` extension of file. Do you know why `.mjs` changing behaviour of nextTick priority?

Comment: Darn it, I thought about a difference in module loaders then didn't try it; I see the same thing you do when I use ESM. I **suspect** the module's top-level code gets run within a microtask in the ESM loader but not in the CJS loader, which (I suspect) runs the module code as a task. A quick test replacing `setTimeout(() => {` with `Promise.resolve().then(() => {` in a non-ESM module seems to confirm that suspicion, as it produces the same output the no-wrapper version does in an ESM module. But it's just a suspicion. You'd have to look at the ESM loader code to be sure. ...

Comment: ... And it underscores the point: Don't rely on the exact timing of unrelated asynchronous processes. You **will** get bitten by unexpected results. :-)